# How to update django-session without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, django, e-commerce

I am trying to add an item to the session without refreshing the page.
I am able to add as many items as but I can only see them after refreshing the page.
This is the sample code I used to add items without page refreshing.

`<iframe name="hiddenFrame" width="0" height="0" border="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<form action="{% url 'myurl' 'id' %}" method="post" class="form-inline" target="hiddenFrame">`

Any idea how to update django-sessions without refreshing the page?

Comment: Thought about  ajax?

Comment: `request.session.modified = True` this one updated the session without redirecting. I am not good at ajax requests.

Comment: If you do not want the page to be refreshed, some asynchronous communication is necessary - if not self created ajax then you need to look for another option of asynchronous communication. (django-celery maybe?)